# after apt update && upgrade xfce about notifications glitch - how to get rid of them?

Tags: kali-linux, xfce, upgrade, software-updates

the first thing that should be noted is that I'm a novice Linux user (I think that this may be the part of the problem).

I'm running Kali Linux with xfce desktop on VMWare Workstation 15 and everything was smooth up till today when I ran `apt update && apt upgrade -y -y` after a longer period of time (for a few months I wasn't using this VM and started using it again yesterday). I went to grab lunch and wanted to pause it - instead, I misclicked shut down. No biggie right? That's what I've thought.

After lunch when I came back and booted up **some windows with versions of different programs appeared in the middle of the screen (I suppose that was information about each piece of software that got upgraded and its current version)** so I nonchalantly started closing them. There were lots of them, but since it was updated after a rather long time, I wasn't surprised. Then the problem appeared - **few windows (? I'm not 100% sure what it is) were still glitching in the middle of the screen and there was no way of closing them.**

I tried to google it as best as I could but I wasn't able to find any helpful information, so as a brave noob I opened the terminal and tried to do my best analysis of the problem. Unsurprisingly, the only thing that I was able to try was several restarts (didn't help), identifying the problematic app/ process, and killing it (not successful).

It's Kali Linux so there are no hard feelings of losing everything (in fact almost nothing) and resetting it, but I'm curious what the problem is... Can anyone help please and suggest further steps?

**gyazo gif of `ps -aux | grep xfce`**: https://gyazo.com/c0e1a82b8adc54516078236780951422

Comment: novice Linux user and Kali: yep, don't do that. Kali assumes you're experienced with Linux. Almost literally any other Linux distro would be better for your use case.

Comment: Citing kali.org's "[Should I Use Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/)": *it is **NOT** a recommended distribution if you’re unfamiliar with Linux or are looking for a general-purpose Linux desktop distribution for development, web design, gaming, etc.* (emphasis by Kali.)

Comment: kali is rolling release, and not invested at all in keeping updates over a longer period of time working. So, this not working is simply "Well, Kali, as promised by Kali, nothing more, nothing less".

Answer (score 0):

The direct cause of this strange behavior was not found and so I decided to change the desktop environment which helped. (changed from xfce to gnome and then back to xfce)